# How to hide my firebase configs to the public?

Tags: firebase

When I do inspect element in my Wordpress website, I see that my firebase credentials are publicly exposed ! so that anyone can see them.

Is there any way to hide them ??

```
    const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***************",
  authDomain: "******************",
  databaseURL: "************",
  projectId: "************",
  storageBucket: "*********",
  messagingSenderId: "******",
  appId: "*******",
  measurementId: "*****"
};
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.auth().languageCode = "fr_FR"
```

Comment: As I answered to the linked question: what you're showing is **configuration** and not a secret. In fact, there is no way for your app to talk directly to Firebase's backend services without this configuration data. So the only way to hide it would be to use a server as a middle-man between your app and Firebase, but in that case you'd be replacing this configuration data with the URL of your server (which is also configuration data).

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object) it is proper way to include a config in the project. Maybe this [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public) post will answer some of your concerns?

You can also read up on this subject [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#config-files-objects).